# How to encode a URL with the special character "percentage"?

Tags: java, jsp, url, encoding

I am trying to use the `encodeURL` method in a jsp to encode a URL with "%" symbol.

`response.encodeURL(/page1/page2/view.jsp?name=Population of 91% in this place)`

Whenever the button is clicked, `"The website cannot display the page"` error is shown.

But when you manually change the `"%"` symbol to `"%25"` like this "`Population of 91%25 in this place`",then the correct page is displayed.

Also whenever the `"%"` symbol is placed at last like this "`In this place Population of 91%`", then the page is correctly displayed but i noticed that in the address bar its still shown as `"%"` and not as `"%25"` and still its working.

When I searched around, its mentioned only to use the other methods like `encodeURI() & encodeURIComponent().`

Can you suggest me a solution while still using the `encodeURL` method to display the pages correctly even if there is a `"%"` symbol. Should i use `replace()` or why isnt the `encodeURL()` method working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html).

Answer (score 1):

The result of your code is :

```
%2Fpage1%2Fpage2%2Fview.jsp%3Fname%3DPopulation%20of%2091%25%20in%20this%20place
```

You should encode only the query string value.

```
... = "/page1/page2/view.jsp?name=" + URLEncoder.encode('Population of 91% in this place');
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The [`HttpServletResponse#encodeURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeURL%28java.lang.String%29) method has actually a misleading name. Read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeURL%28java.lang.String%29) to learn what it really does (appending the `jsessionid` if necessary). See also [In the context of Java Servlet what is the difference between URL Rewriting and Forwarding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949034/in-the-context-of-java-servlet-what-is-the-difference-between-url-rewriting-and) to learn about ambiguties in JSP/Servlet world.

In the servlet side, you need [`URLEncoder#encode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead:

```
String url = "/page1/page2/view.jsp?name=" + URLEncoder.encode("Population of 91% in this place", "UTF-8");
// ...
```

In the JSP side, however, you need the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:url>` tag instead ([avoid Java code in JSP!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)):

```html
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...

<c:url var="url" value="/page1/page2/view.jsp">
  <c:param name="name" value="Population of 91% in this place" />
</c:url>

<a href="${url}">link</a>

<form action="${url}">
  <input type="submit" value="button" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can use the `c:url` and `c:param` tags:

```
<c:url value="/page1/page2/view.jsp">
    <c:param name="name" value="Population of 91% in this place" />
</c:url>
```

In particular, the `c:param` tag will url-encode the value attribute.  I just ran into a situation where I needed to generate a URL with a querystring containing a value that started with a pound sign.  Without url-encoding, the pound sign was interpreted by the browser as the start of the anchor portion.  I added the `c:param` tag, and the pound sign was encoded, allowing expected behavior when following the link.