# Get rid of ;jsessionid=xxx path parameter in URL when using h:button

Tags: jsf-2, omnifaces, jsessionid

I'm using [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`FullAjaxExceptionHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) in Tomcat7 and JSF 2.1 to handle the `ViewExpiredException`. I've setup the same error pages as OmniFaces showcase. [Look here for error pages](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase/tree/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/errorpages) and [here for template](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/templates/errorpage.xhtml).

It works fine. When the session is expired, then I end up in `expired.xhtml` error page. However, when I click the below link in the error page,

```
 <p><a href="#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.request_uri']}">Back to initial page.</a></p>
```

then I get the following exception:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean
```

This is not a big problem. I need a button that points the user to the home page anyway. So I replaced it by the below button:

```
<h:button value="Home" outcome="logout" />
```

along with this navigation case:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/stdPortal/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

The navigation took me to the correct page, however the session ID appears in the URL:

```
https://localhost/stdPortal/index.xhtml;jsessionid=B68784B4ED8882A6575A2EE4012AF1B5
```

I don't want this. How do I get rid of it? I want the URL to be like:

```
https://localhost/stdPortal/index.xhtml
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get rid of `jsessionid` path fragment in URL by adding the following to `web.xml`:

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

It basically disables [URL-rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949034/in-the-context-of-java-servlet-what-is-the-difference-between-url-rewriting-and/7950551#7950551).

Comment: @ BalusC as usual a Genius. You always understand the problem and provide the perfect solution. Not knowing that they must seek "jsessionid path fragment" I could not find the solution.
why jsession is stored in url is a TomcatBug or are some tech problem

Comment: The `jsessionid` path fragment will be appended to URLs if the new session has been established while the response is already committed. Increasing the response buffer size to the same size as your largest page should also help.