# Cannot forward to JSF page using URL with context path

Tags: jsf, servlets

I was trying to forward a request to a JSF page:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(redirectURI).forward(request, response);
```

I have a `proc.xhtml` under `pages`.

If I set:

```
redirectURI = "pages/proc.xhtml";
```

and it works fine.

However if I use the absolute URL including the context path:

```
redirectURI = "/context/pages/proc.xhtml";
```

It does not work and give me this exception:

```
com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /context/pages/proc.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource.
```

(and yes I set the Faces servlet URL pattern to be `*.xhtml` already)

Comment: Have you tried `redirectURI=/pages/proc.jsf`  What is the output you get for this?

Comment: @VikasV I set `redirectURI=/pages/proc.xhtml` and it works... Not sure why adding the context path in the beginning will not work because that is more intuitive and conforming to URL rules...

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and put a `/` in `redirectURI = "pages/proc.xhtml"`. It confuses.

Comment: @VikasV both `pages/proc.xhtml` and `/pages/proc.xhtml` works. It just does not work when I use `/context/pages/proc.xhtml`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) takes a path relative to the context root. So, essentially you're trying to forward to `/context/context/pages/proc.xhtml` which obviously doesn't exist. You need `/pages/proc.xhtml` if you want to make it absolutely relative to the context root instead of to the current request URI.

```
redirectURI = "/pages/proc.xhtml";
```

Or, as the in this context strange variable name `redirectURI` indicates, if you *actually* intend to fire a **real** redirect (and thus reflect the URL change in the browser's address bar), then you should be using [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) instead which indeed takes a path relative to the current request URI (and thus you should include the context path when you want to start with `/`).

```
redirectURI = request.getContextPath() + "/pages/proc.xhtml";
response.sendRedirect(redirectURI);
```

Otherwise better rename that variable to `forwardURI` or so.

#### See also:

- [What is the difference between redirect and navigation/forward and when to use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w/)
- [In the context of Java Servlet what is the difference between URL Rewriting and Forwarding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949034/in-the-context-of-java-servlet-what-is-the-difference-between-url-rewriting-and/)